# Applying for UK Visa as a student from another country for tourism purposes

Tags: visas, uk

I am a student from Indonesia studying in Singapore. I am applying for Standard visitor visa for the UK.
The requirements state that I need to provide that I am able to financially support myself.
If I put my mom as my sponsor to go to UK financially (she is traveling with me too), is the reason strong enough for me to be able to get a UK visa?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TSE, It is difficult for us to be able to asses the situation and advise that your reasoning is strong enough. If your mom is traveling with you there is no harm if she sponsors your finances as well. But whether that is enough on its own is hard to tell.